# Table with fixed header using JS does not work in Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I have this [website](http://develop.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/en/apartments.html) with a table with a fixed header (`thead`).

To fix it I'm using this script that works in Firefox, Chrome and Safari but not in Internet Explorer.

```
document.getElementById("wrap").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
    this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});
```

How can I fix it via JS?

Comment: Try `overflow:auto!important;` in `navbar`

Answer (score 0):

What version of internet explorer are you targeting ?

transform is only available for ie9+, ie9 requires a -ms- prefix for the property.

so to achieve this in javascript you also need to add ...style.msTransform

Comment: I tried with version 6 and 11. And dows not works. Even if i add style.msTransform